# Filter batch file cmd output to file

Tags: batch-file, filtering

i have the below script running to show all current connections to our servers, is there a way to filter this when it writes to the file only to give the active sessions?

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Delete previous output file
del currentsessions.txt
FOR /F "delims=," %%i IN (AXServers.txt) DO (
echo %%i >> currentsessions.txt
QUERY SESSION /SERVER:%%i >> currentsessions.txt
)
```

and output is as follows currently

[QuerySessionsResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmEPQ.jpg)

Comment: which sessions you consider as active?

Comment: Those in the Active state, should of been more clear on that i guess.

Comment: just try `echo %%i|find "Active" >>currentsessions.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work following comment from npocmaka, adjusted to the following code.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Delete previous output file
del currentsessions.txt
FOR /F "delims=," %%i IN (AXServers.txt) DO (
echo %%i >> currentsessions.txt
QUERY SESSION /SERVER:%%i|find "Active" >> currentsessions.txt
)
```